# How to make the clock sync automatically after suspension of a Virtual Machine

Tags: suspend, virtualization, vmware, clock

I run Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit as a guest OS on a VMWare Player machine over Windows 7. I have the clock displayed in the panel and the location set to my time zone. Occasionally, I close VMWare Player using the **VM** -> **Power** -> **Suspend** menu. When I turn the Ubuntu on again, the clock is no longer in sync with the real system clock.

How can I make the clock to auto sync when the system is resumed from suspension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is a function of the open-vm-tools package. On the guest VM:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
```

Comment: I installed the package, then, during installation I was asked if I want to replace (or something similar) a few already existing programs from the VMware tools set. I declined and let the installation finish. At night the VM was suspended and after resuming this morning, it looks like the clock is in perfect sync with the Win 7 clock. So, for now it looks like this is a solution to the problem.